# ¿Por qué decimos que "pintan bastos" cuando se presentan mal las cosas?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa, locuciones

La locución adverbial "[pintar bastos](https://dle.rae.es/basto#5C407cE)" tiene el sentido de

> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Esp. **Presentarse mal las cosas**.

El verbo "[pintar](https://dle.rae.es/pintar?m=form)" tiene varias acepciones, entre ellas, relevantes para este contexto:

11. intr. Dicho de un palo de la baraja: **Ser el triunfo en el juego**. Pintan oros.
12. intr. coloq. **Presentarse o empezar a mostrarse de una determinada manera**. Las cosas pintan muy bien.

Los bastos son un palo de la baraja que si no me equivoco representa el poder del pueblo (las copas o cálices son el poder eclesiástico, las espadas el militar y los oros el poder económico). Por esta acepción no le veo ningún sentido a la locución adverbial, ni como que el palo es el triunfo del juego ni que se presentan así las cosas.

Puede ser que la acepción de "basto" sea más literal (con respecto al dibujo tradicional) y que signifique "palo" o "garrote" (garrotazo). Por tanto, "pintar bastos" podría significar "los palos o garrotes van a ser triunfo del juego o la carta que hay que jugar". Es decir "hay que darse *de palos*" o pelear y que esto llegase a significar "se ponen difíciles las cosas".

O podría ser como en la decimotercera acepción y significar "parece que se presentan las cosas como que hay que darse de palos o garrotazos (o que nos van a dar palos y garrotazos)".

Pero todo esto es mera especulación, y no he conseguido encontrar referencias claras buscando en internet.

¿Puede alguien arrojar algo de luz sobre el origen de esta expresión?

Answer (score 2):

[WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pintan-bastos.2797563/):

> ... es como si hubiera un doble juego de palabras.
> Pintar: tener tal aspecto (por ejemplo: la situación pinta mal, o sea, tiene mal aspecto); pero cuando juegas a las cartas, "pintar" se dice del palo de la baraja que es el dominante en la partida: pintan copas (significa que las copas son el palo dominante, el que triunfa sobre los demás palos).
> Bastos: son uno de los palos de la baraja española (oros, copas, espadas y bastos); pero en esa expresión ("pintan bastos"), tiene el doble sentido de algo que golpea, algo que te hace daño o es perjudicial.
> Así, "pintan bastos", en sentido literal: en esta partida mandan los bastos (por encima de las copas, las espadas y los oros).
> Pero en sentido figurado: la situación es mala, o peligrosa (tiene muy mal aspecto).
>
> O sea que las dos palabras tienen doble sentido.

[1de3](http://www.1de3.es/2012/03/24/pintan-bastos/):

> ¿Sabías por qué decimos que PINTAN BASTOS cuando una situación se complica hasta el punto de poder salir perjudicados de ella?
>
> La expresión tiene su origen en los juegos de naipes.
>
> La pinta es la orla o línea que enmarca los naipes y que indica de qué palo son antes de descubrirlos, ya que cada palo tiene un diferente número de rayas: oros tiene una, copas tiene dos, espadas tiene tres y bastos tiene cuatro.
>
> Cuando la carta de muestra o triunfo es una de copas se dice que pintan copas, significando con ello que las cartas de ese palo pueden, en esa partida, ganar a las de los otros palos.
>
> Por su parte, los diferentes palos de la baraja española representan cada uno de ellos a un estamento social diferente: los oros al poder económico, las copas (cálices) al poder eclesiástico, las espadas al poder militar y los bastos (campesinos) al poder popular.
>
> No es difícil imaginar que una situación en la que lleven las de ganar un grupo de campesinos armados con garrotes, sea una situación complicada de la que será muy difícil no salir malparado.

[Minoriadeunosolo](https://www.minoriadeunosolo.es/2013/09/modismos-pintan-bastos.html):

> En alguna ocasión he oído el modismo "Pintan Bastos", para referirse a que todo apunta a que la situación es muy probable que empeore. Pero, como siempre, ¿de dónde viene esta expresión?
>
> Por un lado tenemos la referencia a la los "Bastos" de la baraja española, y su relación con algo rudo. No olvidemos que cada palo esta asociado a una clase social.
>
> Oros Realeza
> Espadas: Nobleza
> Bastos: El pueblo
> Copas: Un cáliz, el Clero
>
> Hasta ahí todo bien. Pero, ¿qué es eso de "pintan"? En primera instancia eso de "pintar" parece que hace referencia a "parecer", pero aplicado a una carta, a priori, no tiene mucho sentido, ya que una carta la vemos o no la vemos, pero no "parece".
>
> Pero, de nuevo, me sorprendió la polisemia de nuestra querida lengua. Resulta que la palabra "pinta" tiene un signifcado muy específico para los naipes.
>
> **Pinta**: 6. f. Señal que tienen los naipes en sus extremos, por donde se conoce, sin descubrirlos por entero, de qué palo son.
> ...
> Como podrás comprobar en la parte superior (y también en la inferior) de las cartas de la baraja española existen unas líneas que cambian según el palo al que pertenezcan.
>
> Así tenemos un orden para los palos:
>
> 0 huecos (línea continua) Oro
> 1 hueco Copas
> 2 huecos Espadas
> 3 huecos Bastos
>
> Que "casualmente" coincide con el orden social de cada uno de los palos: Nobles, Sacerdotes, Caballeros y el pueblo llano.

De hecho, hay un refrán relacionado: "De tejas arriba, un Dios clemente; de tejas abajo, son bastos los que pintan".

Answer (score 2):

Para mí la teoría más simple es que, según [una teoría](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baraja_espa%C3%B1ola), los palos de la baraja representan:

- Oros, el comercio, o aquello para lo que el dinero sea representativo.
- Copas, el sacerdocio, los clérigos.
- Espadas, al soberano, nobles y militares.
- Bastos, la agricultura.

Siguiendo este esquema, se podría entender que el palo de bastos es el opuesto al de oros, es decir, aquel más pobre, que tiene menos dinero. Luego si *pintan bastos*, es decir, el palo de bastos es el que triunfa en la partida actual, se podría entender como que viene una mala época.

Hay usos de la expresión al menos desde el siglo XIX. Por ejemplo:

> *En la situación actual pintan bastos.*
>
> **El Imparcial (Madrid).** 31/10/1877, [página 2](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000547721&page=2&search=%22pintan%20bastos%22%20%22pintaban%20bastos%22&lang=es).

Y uno un poco menos genérico, ambientado en el mundo del toro:

> *Un pase alto y otro pinchazo en hueso.
>
> Esta tarde se conoce que pintaban bastos, según el decir de un aficionado.*
>
> **El Toreo (Madrid).** 29/3/1897, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000907222&page=3&search=%22pintan%20bastos%22%20%22pintaban%20bastos%22&lang=es).

Un ejemplo de esta contraposición bastos/oros lo tienes en el siguiente ejemplo:

> *Para nosotros, para los revisteros, siguen las espinas. A nosotros no se nos considera nunca; ni cuando pintan bastos, ni cuando pintan oros.*
>
> **El Liberal (Madrid).** 21/3/1911, [página 4](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001601282&page=4&search=%22pintan%20bastos%22%20%22pintaban%20bastos%22&lang=es).

Se ve aquí pues que bastos se considera el opuesto a oros, como indicando una época de escasez frente a una de opulencia.

Esta es mi teoría principal, aunque tengo otra que considero menos probable mas no por ello debo dejar de exponerla, y es que tenga que ver con el dicho *meter el dos de bastos*, que se refería allá por el siglo XVII a cuando un ladrón te metía dos dedos en la faltriquera para robarte el dinero.

> *Hablando el* Buscón de Quevedo *de sus ascendientes, refiere que «malas lenguas daban en decir que mi padre* metía el dos de bastos *para sacar el as de oros.»*
>
> **La Ilustración española y americana.** 30/9/1884, [página 9](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001118617&page=9&search=%22dos%20de%20bastos%22&lang=es).

No sé qué conexión, si es que la hay, pudo haber entre este dicho y el que nos ocupa, pero ahí dejo la posibilidad. Insisto en que considero mi primera opción más plausible.